# No email sending using smtplib - python

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail, smtplib

```
import smtplib

sender = 'den.callanan@gmail.com'
receiver = ['callanden@gmail.com']

message = """From: From Person <den.callanan@gmail.com>
To: To Person <callanden@gmail.com>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

This is a test e-mail message.
"""

try:

    print("trying host and port...")

    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 465)

    print("sending mail...")

    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receiver, message)

    print("Succesfully sent email")

except SMTPException:

    print("Error: unable to send email")
```

I've created two new email accounts (above), both on the same server (gmail) to test this.
It reaches the point in which it prints "trying host and port..." and does not go any further. So the problem should be with the address and port number I entered. But according to gmail's outgoing mail server details i've inputted them correctly. Any ideas what's wrong?

If I remove the port number or try a different port number such as 587 i'm provided with an error.

Comment: Enable diagnostics from `smtplib` so you can see where it's going wrong. At this level of detail, all we can do is guess. My guess would be that Gmail requires authentication, in which case see any of the imperial crapload of near-duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

[Sending email via Gmail's SMTP servers requires TLS](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en) and authentication. To authenticate, you will need to [make an application-specific password for your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833).

This script worked for me (though I used my own GMail email address and my own application-specific password). In the code below, replace APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD with the password you generated.

```
import smtplib

sender = 'den.callanan@gmail.com'
receiver = ['callanden@gmail.com']

message = """From: From Person <den.callanan@gmail.com>
To: To Person <callanden@gmail.com>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

This is a test e-mail message.
"""

try:
    print("trying host and port...")

    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    smtpObj.login("den.callanan@gmail.com", "APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD")

    print("sending mail...")

    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receiver, message)

    print("Succesfully sent email")

except smtplib.SMTPException:
    print("Error: unable to send email")
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
```

(To debug the problem, I added the print-traceback code in the except statement. The exceptions had specific information on how to get it to work. The code hung when accessing port 465, I think because of problems with TLS negotiation, so I had to try using port 587; then I got good debugging info that explained what to do.)

[You can see info on the SMTP_SSL object here.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html)